# Como subir formulario con imagenes con ajax y php

Tags: php, ajax

Estimados tengo el siguiente formulario tipo modal

```
<div class="modal fade border-0" id="form-conformado" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content formularios">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-add-to-list icon-titulo"></i>Registro ID Conformado</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="borrar_inputs();"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-row">                      
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-2 col-6">
                        <label for="id">ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-resp" name="id" id="id" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
                    </div>    
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-6">
                        <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-resp" name="fecha" id="fecha" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y");?>">
                    </div>              
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-7 col-12 input_producto"></div>           
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-5">
                        <label for="produccion">Producción</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-resp" name="produccion" id="produccion" value="0">
                    </div>              
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-7 input_maquina"></div> 
                                        
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-12">
                        <label for="operador">Operador</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-resp" name="operador" id="operador" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" autocomplete="off" onClick="this.select();">
                        <div class="listado_operadores reg_operadores"></div>           
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-5 col-12">
                        <label for="observaciones">Observaciones</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="observaciones" id="observaciones" cols="30" rows="3" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></textarea>
                    </div>                                  
                </div>                          
            </div>              
            <div class="modal-footer p-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="actualizar-registros"><h5 class="icon-spinner11 m-0"></h5></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="insertar-registros"><h5 class="icon-save m-0"></h5></button>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Uso Ajax para enviar los datos de la siguiente forma

```
 function insertar_registros(){     
        var action = 'fetch_data';   
        var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
        var codigoproducto = document.getElementById("producto").value;  
        var largo = codigoproducto.length;
        var posicion = codigoproducto.indexOf("]");
        var codigo = codigoproducto.substr(1,posicion-1);
        var producto = codigoproducto.substr(posicion+4,largo-posicion-4);
        var produccion = document.getElementById("produccion").value;        
        var maquina = document.getElementById("maquina").value;    
        var operador = document.getElementById("operador").value;
        var fecha = document.getElementById("fecha").value; 
        var observaciones = document.getElementById("observaciones").value; 
        $.ajax({        
            url:"<?php echo $raiz;?>registrar/registrar_id_conformado.php", 
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:{action:action,id:id,codigo:codigo,producto:producto,produccion:produccion,maquina:maquina,operador:operador,fecha:fecha,observaciones:observaciones},        
            success:function(data){
                if(data.html1 == 'Registro realizado exitosamente'){                        
                    borrar_inputs();                    
                    mostrar_registros();
                    $('#registro_correcto').modal('show');  
                }else if(data.html1 == 'Existen campos vacios que deben ser llenados'){
                    $('#faltan_datos').modal('show');                               
                }else if(data.html1 == 'El ID ya existe'){
                    $('#registro_duplicado').modal('show');                                                 
                }  
            }
        });             
    }
```

Recibo los datos en php de forma normal con

```
$_POST['nombre'];
```

Quiero agregar en el mismo formulario un input para subir imagenes

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="imagenes[]" id="imagenes" multiple>
```

Usando la misma funcion ajax quiero pasar las imagenes a subir, pero no se como pasarlas en la parte de data, para luego recibirlas en php, todo junto quedaria asi hasta el momento

```
function insertar_registros(){      
        var action = 'fetch_data';   
        var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
        var codigoproducto = document.getElementById("producto").value;  
        var largo = codigoproducto.length;
        var posicion = codigoproducto.indexOf("]");
        var codigo = codigoproducto.substr(1,posicion-1);
        var producto = codigoproducto.substr(posicion+4,largo-posicion-4);
        var produccion = document.getElementById("produccion").value;        
        var maquina = document.getElementById("maquina").value;    
        var operador = document.getElementById("operador").value;
        var fecha = document.getElementById("fecha").value; 
        var observaciones = document.getElementById("observaciones").value; 
        var archivos = document.getElementById('imagenes');
        var archivo = archivos.files;
        var imagenes = new FormData();
        for(i=0;i<archivo.length,i++){
            imagenes.append('archivo'+i,archivo[i]);            
        }
        $.ajax({        
            url:"<?php echo $raiz;?>registrar/registrar_id_conformado.php", 
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:{action:action,id:id,codigo:codigo,producto:producto,produccion:produccion,maquina:maquina,operador:operador,fecha:fecha,observaciones:observaciones},        
            success:function(data){
                if(data.html1 == 'Registro realizado exitosamente'){                        
                    borrar_inputs();                    
                    mostrar_registros();
                    $('#registro_correcto').modal('show');  
                }else if(data.html1 == 'Existen campos vacios que deben ser llenados'){
                    $('#faltan_datos').modal('show');                               
                }else if(data.html1 == 'El ID ya existe'){
                    $('#registro_duplicado').modal('show');                                                 
                }  
            }
        });             
    }
```

Estoy estancado en la parte de **Data** en Ajax y en como recibir despues esas imagenes en php, como puedo hacerlo ?

Answer (score -1):

Para enviar archivos por medio de una peticion http debes hacerlo con FormData es decir, agregar todos tus datos a un objeto FormData incluido el o los archivos y enviar ese objeto con otros parametros mas en las configuraciones de esa consulta ajax, es decir en el parametro data solo enviarias el FormData.

adicionalmente deber agregar estos parametros a las configuraciones de esa consulta.

```
processData: false,
contentType : false
```

quedando de la siguiente manera

```
$.ajax({        
        url:"<?php echo $raiz;?>registrar/registrar_id_conformado.php", 
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data:FormData, //el nombre del objeto FormData que hayas creado con todos los dastos y archivos

    });
```

Comment: Es una buena respuesta, pero incompleta. ¿Porqué no das un ejemplo de cómo adjuntar una imagen al objeto FormData?